# ROW_NUMBER() in Postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im trying to add ROW_NUMBER() in a select query on top of a calculated field and get unique rownum for unique calculated field. But Im getting sequuential rownum for all the values in calculated field.

How can I achieve it in Postgres SQL?

Thanks in advance.

```
select m.subscriber, count(distinct s.session_id)  as num_session 
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by count(distinct s.session_id) ORDER BY count(distinct s.session_id) DESC) AS rownum
from dbms.music_stream m, dbms.session s, dbms.users u
where  m.session_id = s.session_id
and m.subscriber = u.user_id
and lower(u.subscription_type) = 'premium'
and lower(s.platform) = 'app'
group by m.subscriber
```

Im applying row_number on count(distinct s.session_id) and I expect the distinct value of count(distinct s.session_id) have same rownum but I get it in an order as below.

```
 subscriber | num_session | rownum 
------------+-------------+--------
        118 |           2 |      1
         73 |           2 |      2
        139 |           2 |      3
         59 |           2 |      4
         81 |           1 |      1
        103 |           1 |      2
```

But this is what I expect :

```
 subscriber | num_session | rownum 
------------+-------------+--------
        118 |           2 |      1
         73 |           2 |      1
        139 |           2 |      1
         59 |           2 |      1
         81 |           1 |      2
        103 |           1 |      2
```

Comment: You're probably looking for DENSE_RANK() and not ROW_NUMBER()

Answer (score 1):

You want `DENSE_RANK()`, not `ROW_NUMBER()`, and also do not include any partition:

```sql
SELECT
    m.subscriber,
    COUNT(DISTINCT s.session_id) AS num_session,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT s.session_id) DESC) AS rownum
FROM dbms.music_stream m
INNER JOIN dbms.session s ON m.session_id = s.session_id
INNER JOIN dbms.users u ON m.subscriber = u.user_id
WHERE LOWER(u.subscription_type) = 'premium' AND
      LOWER(s.platform) = 'app'
GROUP BY m.subscriber;
```

Note also that I replaced your old school implicit joins with modern explicit inner joins.  Putting commas in the `FROM` clause is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.subscriber as user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.gender, count(distinct s.session_id)  as num_session 
,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY count(distinct s.session_id) DESC) as rank
from dbms.music_stream m, dbms.session s, dbms.users u
where  m.session_id = s.session_id
and m.subscriber = u.user_id
and lower(u.subscription_type) = 'premium'
and lower(s.platform) = 'app'
group by m.subscriber, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.gender
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).